# problems in block diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a question regarding making block diagrams in latex.
my code generated a block diagram (the left one), However, I want the connections to look like the sample figure(right). How to do that ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows}
\begin{document}
%\tikzstyle{decision}{line}=[draw,-latex']
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw,-stealth,thick]
\tikzstyle{block}=[draw,rectangle,fill=blue!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm, node distance=10em]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block] (start) {START};
\node [block, below of=start] (end) {END};  
\node [block, left of=end] (another) {ANOTHER};
\node [block, right of=end] (another1) {ANOTHER1};

%arrows
\path [line] (start) -- (end);
\path [line] (start) -| (another);
\path [line] (start) -| (another1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place an auxiliary coordinate in the middle of the path from `start` to `end`:

```
\path [line] (start) -- coordinate[midway] (aux) (end);
```

and then use this coordinate to bend the arrows at that location:

```
\path [line] (start) -- (aux) -| (another);
\path [line] (start) -- (aux) -| (another1);
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
line/.style={draw,-stealth,thick},
block/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=blue!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm,}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [block] (start) {START};
\node [block, below = of start] (end) {END};  
\node [block, left = of end] (another) {ANOTHER};
\node [block, right = of end] (another1) {ANOTHER1};

%arrows
\path [line] (start) -- coordinate[midway] (aux) (end);
\path [line] (start) -- (aux) -| (another);
\path [line] (start) -- (aux) -| (another1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- I changed the old `\tikzstyle` syntax for the more convenient `\tikzset` syntax.
- I changed the deprecated `of=` syntax to the more appropriate `=of` syntax with the positioning library.

Since your graph is a tree, the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package (built upon TikZ) might be of interest for you; here's the same graph using forest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning}

\tikzset{
line/.style={draw,-stealth,thick},
block/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=blue!50, text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=15mm,}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  block,
  parent anchor=south,
  child anchor=north,
  l sep=20pt,
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-10pt) -|   
      (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  edge={->,>=latex}
} 
[START
  [ANOTHER
  ]
  [END
  ]
  [ANOTHER1
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]